# Methods related to UILabel drawing/appearing on screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alignment, uilabel

I'm new to iOS development so help me out here, I know iOS provides methods related to UIViews when then appear on screen, ViewWillAppear & ViewDidAppear, does iOS also provide such type of methods for UILabel too? I want to set my custom alignment to all the labels used in my app, when they appear on screen, so I want to do it using extension, would it be possible ?

Comment: what you mean with custom alignment?

Comment: @ReinierMelian in my project there are multiple labels in multiple view, each having different alignment, I want to apply same alignment to all the existing & future labels.

Comment: `viewDidLoad`/`viewDidAppear`/etc. are all methods on`UIViewController`, not `UIView`. If you have a custom subclass of `UILabel` (which inherits from `UIView`), you can override something like `awakeFromNib` (if you're using .xibs or storyboards) or `layoutSubviews`

Comment: but you are talking about textAlignment?

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes I want all the labels of app to have RightAlignment or LeftAlignment depending upon a condition.

Comment: @Zubair you can subclass UILabel and in your customUILabel in `layoutSubviews` method you can set the textAligment

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thanks, that's what I was looking for, post it as a answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @MichaelHulet I tried but it doesn't work. `layoutSubviews` worked fro me.

Comment: added as an answer @Zubair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear are not the methods of UIView, these are the methods of UIViewController's lifecycle.
UIView has methods like **layoutSubviews** and **draw(_ rect: CGRect)** which you can override to provide your own implementation for the UIView.
Now UILabel is a subclass of UIView, so you can use these methods for your UILabel.
What you want to do is to make a custom class which will inherit from UILabel, and override **layoutSubviews** or **draw(_ rect: CGRect)** method to provide your required CGRect. And then use that custom label throughout your app.
Here's an example of how you can achieve this.

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {

    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
         super.layoutSubviews()
         //change your frame here according to your needs.
    }
}
`
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, nice addition to my concepts :)

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass `UILabel` and in your CustomUILabel in `layoutSubviews` method you can set the textAlignment

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class LeftAlignedUILabel: UILabel {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setup()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setup()
    }


    func setup(){
        textAlignment = .left
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the idea from & applied it like this
`extension UILable {
    open override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }

    func setup(){
        self.textAlignment = .left
    }
}`

Comment: better @Zubair I use a subclass because if you need not all your UILabels have the same alignment, but if you need all of them left alignment an extension is even better, best regards

Comment: in this particular case I need to apply same alignment to all the labels, thats why used extension otherwise I got your point, really helpful.